# Partial Views with different model in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i have two class as below

```
Model:-  

     public class RegisterViewModel
        {
             public string Email { get; set; }     
             public AddressPropertyVM AddressProperty { get; set; }
        }

        public class AddressPropertyVM
        {
             public string StreetNo { get; set; }     
        }
Main Form
@model Application.Models.RegisterViewModel
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)

    @Html.Partial("_AddressPropertyPartial",Model.AddressProperty)

    <button type="submit">Register</button>

}

Partial View Form
@model Application.Models.AddressPropertyVM
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetNo)

}
```

I am creating asp.net mvc application.

I have create a partial view for AddressPropertyVM.

but we i post form(main form)  at that time  data of AddressProperty is null.

Comment: can you show the view ?

Comment: My view like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to use one partial view with more than one pages I mean multiple usage of one page in many pages.

Read this [article](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fe1c187c-9d93-4c48-89dc-e497c2a53294.aspx) and understand how it works.

Change your code as per article like below.

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPropertyPartial",Model.AddressProperty)
```

To

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPropertyPartial", Model.AddressProperty,  new ViewDataDictionary()   {     TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()       { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AddressProperty" } }
```